# How can I check if the function each passsed through the entire array (javascript/jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, each

Example this code:

```
$("div.content").each(function() {
     // content
});
```

How can I say to the browser that after read this function start to read other part of the code?

I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
var string = $("div.content").each(function() {
     // content
});
if (string) { // content }
```

Comment: What do you mean by title of your question? I didn't understood your problem, you want to check something inside `.content`? Can you exmplain better what is your problem actually?

Comment: I want to start other function just after finishing to read the entire function each

Comment: Is there anything you're doing that's asynchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use two parameters inside each function method.
check the below code

```
$("div.content").each(function(element, i) {
     console.log(element, i);
     // or add your custom logic on each element 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the index of the current element of the array what you need to do is add another parameter like below. The second parameter will be the index of the element within the array.

```js
$("div.content").each(function(elem, i) {
    //content
});
```